# best strategy to make a website mobile compatible

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am maintaining a legacy website that over the years have become a jungle of broken incorrect, outdated html, iframes, script tags all over the place, a gazillion analytic code snippets, inline css styling,  hardcoded pixel adjustments etc.

However, the fact of the matter is that the site looks perfectly fine in a desktop environment. (It will not break for 1360* 768 resolution and above). And it has a good page ranking in Google. Now that Google is changing its page ranking I need to make this site mobile compatible. I tried using bootstrap and media query, but I think it is a nightmare trying to convert the current html.

What I wanted to check is- are there any other approaches I can use? I am thinking about how I can show a totally different page in the same URL when the user accesses it using a mobile device.

Any pointers are very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It can be kind of impossible to make a nice responsive design from an existing, bad desktop design. It's much easier to start new, with a mobile first approach.

But if you can't, and don't want to destroy the desktop design, you could absolutely transfer mobile users to a different site (like m.domain.com) with JavaScript.

Here is some info: http://blog.woorank.com/2014/06/how-to-redirect-mobile-users-on-your-website/

Comment: Thank you for you answer, would this impact ranking for existing URL if I do this?

Comment: Hmm I forgot about the main question, didn't I? :) Sorry. It's impossible to know, but I don't think that a separate site would imporve your rankings no. You would be better of with media queries - but it can be alot of hacking and the result could be an ugly approach to a mobile site. A new mobile first design is the best you can do (in a perfect world, but I understand :))

Comment: OP asked from Google page ranking point of view. According to Google, they prefer same URL and HTML than a different URL for different devices. See https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/overview/select-config

Answer (score 0):

You can render a different mobile compatible HTML page based on USER-AGENT.
For e.g. you can use pre request processors to check request HEADERS for USER-AGENT and if the pattern matches to any of the mobile ones,

1. you can redirect user to another url e.g. `m.yourwebsite.com`,
2. you can replace the underlying HTML page you're about to render (e.g. Say the url maps to `/path/to/templates`, it changes to `/path/to/mobile templates/`. The file name is the same)
3. you can simply set a variable on request and make decisions inside the HTML file itself. E.g. In templates you can do

   `{% if request.is_mobile %} 
         /url/to/mobile.css 
    {% else %} 
         /url/to/desktop.css
    {% endif %}`

Option 1 is lot of work and option 3 would be least amount of work. We chose option 2. Option 3 isn't recommended because it can make a HTML page buggy (we do it for smaller and mostly static pages like about us  privacy etc)

It seems that Google favors same domain with responsive web design over a sub domain, though jury is still out on it. Here is what [google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/overview/select-config) has to say. So having same URL is preferred way for all devices.